# 240v heater from 120v countdown timer switch using a relay

Tags: 240v, timer, relay

I have a 240v 30amp infrared ceiling mounted heater in my garage for cold days when I want to work out there. It's controlled by a wall mounted thermostat by the same brand (Dr. Heater). I just installed it, and I am concerned that as I flit from task to task on a project that I will forget to turn off the heater, which in a worst case scenario, could try to keep my uninsulated garage at 70 degrees in sub-zero outdoor temps.

I was looking for a countdown timer wall switch to control the line (prior to the thermostat), but of course no one makes a 30amp switch. Well, at least. I found a few but they are ~$200, more than I paid for the heater itself.

I saw [this thread](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/181453/how-can-i-control-a-240v-heater-from-a-pushbutton-timer-switch#new-answer?newreg=af7087a17b584a3e8976cd7967a96327) about adding a relay to a 120v countdown wall switch and that's exactly what I'd like to do, but need clarification on whether an DPST switch would work, as Functional Devices does not have the same switch in a higher amperage. Would [this switch](https://www.functionaldevices.com/product/rib01p30/) work instead? And what changes would I make from the wiring advice given by @ThreePhaseEel, if any?

BTW, I would have just commented on the original post, but I don't have the reputation to comment and all answers are supposed to be "answers", so here we are, at an almost duplicate thread :(.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Nobody makes a 30A switch?](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-30-Amp-Industrial-Double-Pole-Switch-White-R62-03032-2WS/100356941?source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&&mtc=SHOPPING-CM-CML-GGL-D27-027_002_WIRING_DEVIC-NA-NA-NA-SMART-2997116-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NEW-PL3&cm_mmc=SHOPPING-CM-CML-GGL-D27-027_002_WIRING_DEVIC-NA-NA-NA-SMART-2997116-NA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NEW-PL3-71700000093390730-58700007789602690-92700070740571031&gclid=CjwKCAjw7p6aBhBiEiwA83fGuk7UHZtXCurVytD3l2E7UeWWfKRP4HvidYMu8ySqtVmtZinWBa1osxoCfCgQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Comment: [You sure about that?](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Eaton-Double-Pole-White-LED-Toggle-Light-Switch/1002944118?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-elc-_-ggl-_-LIA_ELC_205_Wiring-Devices-Cords-Fire-_-1002944118-_-local-_-0-_-0&ds_rl=1286981&gclid=CjwKCAjw7p6aBhBiEiwA83fGulD0_BNWS01o18Jo9NI4X_L-pYLnyXf0C0TYR_FqnaPQoJ1j9IlbdBoC9N8QAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds)

Comment: OK quick question. The thermostat you installed, did it require you to route big #12 or #10 heavy cable through the thermostat?  Or did it use dinky little #18 thermostat wire?  Also the article you linked is incorrect about digital timers only; the classic Intermatic *spring-wound* timers can work with a relay also, and those are made as long as 12 hours. I love those things!

Comment: Sorry edited my question. Seems like no one makes a 30amp countdown timer switch. I really buggered this one with that missing detail. 

@Harper-ReinstateMonica That's good to know, I've seen a bunch of those around and they are exactly what I had been looking for. If only they had a 30A (20A is as high as I saw). But sounds like I might be able to use one with a relay like in the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The RIB01P30 is what you need here

You are correct in that the RIB01P30 is the correct relay for this job.

### Why not a contactor?

The main issue with contactors is that the cheap home-store models are *definite purpose* contactors that are designed to go into equipment (typically HVAC condensing/outdoor units) and thus don't have the correct ratings (Rather Useless UL component recognition vs a full UL listing) for use outside of equipment (such as in a junction box), and fully UL listed contactors are typically too large for convenient mounting in or on a normal JB -- they're listed to UL 508, but are intended to go into the larger enclosures used for industrial control panels, so shoehorning one into a junction box is quite an awkward task.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That's exactly what I needed to know. After looking at the differences between single and double throw, looks like I should be able to wire it up exactly as you described in the other post.

Comment: As always, a boggling dearth of upvotes for ThreePhaseEel. Improved.

Comment: @threephaseeel I was reading the other advice you gave for the other person trying this (link in original question) and was confused as the wiring for this RIB01P30 looks much different. I have two why/blk 120v ac wires, and then two poles each with two wires, both marked N/O. Wondering how to wire this up using hot and neutral from an incoming 120v line? Do I connect the neutral and hot from the timer and incoming 120v to the two separate 120Vac wires on the relay? Also I don't have yellow common and purple common available on the relay that I see were used in the other post.

Comment: @JoshuaYoung ask your question as its own question and I'll provide an answer suited to yours

Answer (score 1):

You need 3 things:   A contactor rated for at least 30 amps, a small transformer and a low voltage programmable thermostat.

The contactor will do the heavy lifting of providing power or not to your heater.

The small transformer (think like doorbell transformer) will supply the thermostat with power to run it as well as activate the contactor when there is a call for heat.

There are lots of different types of contactors, some of them operate use 120 or 240 for CONTROLS,   You want one that uses 24 volts for the control part so you can use a commonly available, low voltage programmable T-stat.  If you want I can make up a wiring diagram, it's pretty straight forward.

Comment: Sorry George, I left a crucial piece of information out of the question. I'm looking to install a countdown timer switch prior to the thermostat.

Comment: @JoshuaYoung  The thing about a programmable tstat is you can program it  using the "hold until" function.   But of course it's up to you. Just turning a knob is much easier than programming a touch screen every time you want to hold temp for a certain period.   Can't blame you.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of a relay try using an industrial switch box such as this:

[Square D - L211N 30 Amp 120/240-Volt Two-Pole Indoor Light Duty Fusible Safety Switch with Neutral](https://amzn.to/3CSpNnA)

Comment: Thanks for the edit MMC. Computer tech not my strong suit.

Comment: I don't believe this answer meets the OPs requirements. He wanted an **AUTOMATIC PROGRAMMABLE** solution.   Also, a contactor is not a "relay"  Conactors  can handle far more power than relays.   In some cases a thermostat can control a low voltage relay that controls a contactor in really heavy duty situations. But normally a contactor is controlled by a thermostat.   Sorry, but I'm DV'ing your answer.

Comment: "I was looking for a wall switch to control the line (prior to the thermostat), but of course no one makes a 30amp switch. Well, at least. I found a few but they are ~$200, more than I paid for the heater itself." Didn't see anything there about an automatic programable solution.

Comment: Sorry ya'll I edited my question. Was looking for a countdown timer, I missed that very crucial part of the description. Something with push buttons or a spring wound timer. A couple of hours would be ideal but I could get away with 60 minutes (when I start to freeze I'll know it's time to crank the dial).